# Swift системный bottom Sheet при звонке

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Подскажите, возможно ли изменить цвет текста на системном сообщении этом, где номер?

[image: скрин]

Comment: Зачем?) Чем он вам не нравится?)

Answer (score 0):

Можно изменить.

UIKit

У вашего UIViewController изменить `tintColor` на ваш

```
view.tintColor = .black
```

SwiftUI

```
var body: some View {
   HStack {
       Button { showAlert = true } 
       label: { Text("Tap") }
   }
   .tint(.black)
}
```